# Every time new text is displayed in IRC display the new line

Tags: c++, c++11, irc

I am trying to do this:

```
char buffer[256];
while(!buffer.getline){
    printf("%s\n",buffer);   
}
return 0;
```

but I am unable to use getline on buffer.

Is there any other way to do this or possibly a way to use getline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use:

```
cin.getline(buffer,256);
```

so your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char buffer[256];
while(cin.getline(buffer,256)){
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
return 0;
}
```